# Kendo Navbar Does Not Display Correctly for Android Devices

Tags: android, html, css, kendo-ui

I am having trouble getting a Kendo navbar to display correctly on Android devices.  I have already read through the Kendo docs and S.O. regarding adding the following css to fix this issue:

```
.km-android .km-view:not(.km-splitview) {
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I have tried multiple variations of this css and still I cannot get my navbar to match how it looks in iOS.
My basic setup looks like this:

```
        <!-- Kendo Mobile Title Bar -->
        <div data-role="view" data-title="<%= BaseShared.GetPageTitle() %>">
            <div data-role="header">
                <div id="csMainNavId" data-role="navbar">
                    <a id="slide-in-handle" class="pull-left" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" id="menuButton" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>                    
                    <span data-role="view-title" class="title-bar-heading">...</span>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div id="contentPanel" data-role="content">
                <!-- Content ... -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { useNativeScrolling: true });
        </script>
```

My page and navbar work perfectly across all devices except for Android.  The navbar displays at the bottom of my page with the title text hidden by default.  Again, I'm aware that Android reverses the header and the footer order but my issue is that all the documented solutions are not working for some reason.  Am I missing something obvious here?